# Filtering on an array field in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query to get data for a movie:

```
with Movies as (
  select 'Titanic' as title,
  1997 as year, 
  ['Drama',' Romance'] as Genres
)
select * from Movies where title='Titanic'
```

[image]

And to filter by those Records where Genres includes: "Drama":

```
with Movies as (
  select 'Titanic' as title,
  1997 as year, 
  ['Drama',' Romance'] as Genres
)
select * from Movies where "Drama" in UNNEST(Genres)
```

[image]

However, how would I filter by those records that have a genre of Drama but only include those genres I specify (Drama). In other words, I want the result set to look like:

```
title      year         Genres
Titanic    1997         Drama
```

And **Not** include all genres within the record -- I only want those matching genres -- how would I do that?

---

**Update**: after some futzing around, here is what worked for me -- it seems incredibly hack-ish and not really sure why it works (an answer explaining how to better do this would be great), but here it is:

```
with Movies as (
  select 'Titanic' as title,
  1997 as year, 
  ['Drama',' Romance'] as Genres
)
select * from (
  select title, year, g from (select title, year, Genres as g from Movies t0, t0.Genres) group by title, year, g
) where g = 'Drama'
```

**Update 2**: simplified to:

```
with Movies as (
  select 'Titanic' as title,
  1997 as year, 
  ['Drama',' Romance'] as Genres
)
select title, year, Genres from Movies t0, t0.Genres where Genres='Drama'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining with UNNEST:

```
with Movies as (
  select 'Titanic' as title, 1997 as year, ['Drama',' Romance'] as Genres
)
select title, year, Genre 
from Movies, UNNEST(Genres) as Genre
where Genre = "Drama"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. What's the difference between doing `FROM Movies, Genres as Genre` and doing `FROM Movies, UNNEST(Genres) as Genre` ?

Comment: `FROM Movies, Genres as Genre` will just not work, while `FROM Movies, UNNEST(Genres) as Genre` does work :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant sorry that was a typo -- I meant `FROM Movies, Movies.Genres` vs `FROM Movies, UNNEST(Genres)`

Comment: `FROM Movies, Genres as Genre` will try to find another table named `Genres` and will brake if you don't have one.
You could use `from Movies, Movies.Genres as Genre` instead.

Comment: @SergeyGeron I see, so then how does BQ resolve the column of `UNNEST(Genres)` -- which table(s) does it know to look in?

Comment: Such is the syntax. UNNEST gives BigQuery a hint to search for this field inside the other table from WHERE block.

Answer (score 2):

In cases when number of columns is more than just few  - below version can be useful too

```
select * except(Genres)
from Movies, unnest(Genres) as Genre
where Genre = "Drama"
```

with output

[image]

In case if you (for some reason) need to preserve column name as Genres vs. Genre - below should work

```
select * except(Genres, Genre), Genre as Genres
from Movies, unnest(Genres) as Genre
where Genre = "Drama"
```

with output

[image]